# Отображение JFrame выше окна браузера

Tags: java, swing, java-ee

Имеется JSP-файл:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>First JSp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing JSP</h1>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Date,logic.TestClass, logic.Framer" %>
    <p>
    <%
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        Framer fr=new Framer();
        fr.visibled(name);
    %>

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Также имеется класс:

```
public class Framer extends JFrame {

    public void visibled(String label)
    {
        this.setSize(200,200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        JLabel jlabel=new JLabel(label);
        this.add(jlabel);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, что при запуске через браузер окно JFrame оказывается ниже окна браузера, каким образом можно сделать чтобы окно JFrame было выше окна браузера?

Comment: Под ниже, вы имеете в виду по вертикали ниже? Или порядок отображения за окном браузера?

Comment: Что бы окно было выше всех окон, т.е. мне не надо было закрыть окно браузера что бы увидеть свое окно (ближе к глазам)..

Comment: Попробуйте - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front